# Running daemon as non-root user in Upstart script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upstart

I have an upstart script that runs a background daemon that I want to run as a specific non-root user.

The script is here:

[How To Create a Calibre Ebook Server on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-calibre-ebook-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

The relevant bit is here:

```
description "Calibre (ebook manager) content server"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [^2345]

respawn

env USER='myusername'
env PASSWORD='mypassword'
env LIBRARY_PATH='/home/user/calibre-library'
env MAX_COVER='300x400'
env PORT='80'

script
    exec /usr/bin/calibre-server --with-library $LIBRARY_PATH --auto-reload \
                             --max-cover $MAX_COVER --port $PORT \
                             --username $USER --password $PASSWORD
end script
```

The problem: the calibre-server executable is being run as root. I want the executable itself run as user 'myusername', so that it has the permissions of that user, and not the permissions of root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the lines `setuid <USER>` and `setgid <GROUP>` to the file. 
Note that this does not start the process with `<USER>`'s supplemental groups.